# ReBinding Right-Alt Key in XEmacs

Tags: windows, keymapping, xemacs

I'm using XEmacs on Windows 7 installed in MacBookPro.
So I don't have a Control-Key on the right side.
I would like to make the right-option key to work as right-ctrl.

I googled and tried the code below, but it is not working:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'control)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
```

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try KeyTweak software. Remap <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with that.

Comment: Finally i did with AutoHotKey Script:

RAlt::RCtrl
LWin::LAlt
RWin::RAlt